# The graph disappear after change marker style and then change the line color

Tags: highcharts

I have added some function into my graph and all of them work 
separately, but after i changed marker style and then change the line color the graph disappear.
the code looks like this:

```
function(chart){

  $('#colorchange').click(function() {
    chart.series[0].update({color:document.getElementById("selectcolor").value});
  });

  $('#stylechange').click(function() {
    chart.series[0].update({dashStyle: document.getElementById("selectStyle").value});
  });

  $('#pointchange').click(function() {
    var l = chart.series[0].points.length;

    var p = chart.series[0].points;
    for(var len = 0; len < l; len++) {

      p[len].update({
        marker: {
          symbol: document.getElementById("selectpoint").value,
        }
      }, false);
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: can you recreate in a fiddle?

Comment: What do you have in `document.getElementById("selectpoint").value` ? Is that a proper format? Btw, you are missing `chart.redraw()` in `#pointchange` callback.

Comment: thx for your guys help

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why it is happening but I have found a work-around and with it a possible reason :-)

I suppose that when you call `p[len].update({...})` without specifying the `x` and `y` values these values get lost. Therefore when you are calling `chart.series[0].update` the points itself are erased. What makes me wonder is that the points are only erased after the update of the series and not after setting the new marker. Maybe highcharts has some sort of cache that is only rebuild when the series is updated.

A quick fix for your problem is to manually set the x and y properties to their old values when updating the points:

```
p[len].update({
  x: p[len].x,
  y: p[len].y,
  marker: {
    symbol: document.getElementById("selectpoint").value
  }
}, false);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/2wwzgz0p/1/ for a working example. If you remove the lines where the x and y values are set the line disappears after setting the color, just like you experienced.

Comment: it is common practice to accept the answer that solved your problem :-)